# How to select columns from 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

I tried this query but it returns duplicated rows :

```
SELECT * 
FROM type_prospection INNER JOIN etape_prospection e ON type_prospection.type_prosp_id=e.type_prosp_id , 
etape_prospection INNER JOIN transfert ON etape_prospection.prosp_id=transfert.prosp_id 
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
```

So how to write the query correctly because I am not very good in MySQL.

---

**EDIT :**

In fact I want to write the query which is equivalent to this one :

```
SELECT * 
FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection 
ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id 
WHERE etape_prospection.prosp_id IN (select transfert.prosp_id 
                                     from transfert 
                                     where transfert.user_code ='3' 
                                     AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20');
```

My boss doesn't like this query because of the `IN` which makes a table full scan.

Answer (score 0):

The comma is causing you issues. Try this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    type_prospection
        INNER JOIN
                etape_prospection e
                ON type_prospection.type_prosp_id=e.type_prosp_id 
        INNER JOIN
                transfert
                ON e.prosp_id=transfert.prosp_id 
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
```

Comment: It causes error : `Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON type_prospection.type_prosp_id=e.type_prosp_id 
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' at line 4`

Comment: Edited - have a feeling that nested joins might not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT transfert.user_code -- Add other columns here 
FROM    type_prospection INNER JOIN etape_prospection e 
            ON type_prospection.type_prosp_id = e.type_prosp_id
        INNER JOIN transfert  
            ON etape_prospection.prosp_id = transfert.prosp_id 
WHERE transfert.user_code ='3' AND transfert.date_transfert='2012-01-20';
```

Comment: It causes error : `Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'etape_prospection.prosp_id' in 'on clause'`